# Windows 10 lock screen slideshow from RSS doesn't work (RequestSetImageFeedAsync)

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, slideshow, lockscreen, windows-10

I made the app in which I use method public static `IAsyncOperation<SetImageFeedResult> RequestSetImageFeedAsync(Uri syndicationFeedUri)` to play lock screen slideshow from external RSS feed in Windows 8. I use next Uri https://urzagatherer.azure-mobile.net/api/wallpapers and it works perfectly in Windows 8 (8.1). But when I run my App in Windows 10 and set the same Uri, lock screen slideshow doesn't play. Could somebody tell me, what is the problem?
I use following code:

```
SetImageFeedResult result = await LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync(new Uri("https://urzagatherer.azure-mobile.net/api/wallpapers")); 
if (result == SetImageFeedResult.Success) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: the specified URL was set as the default."; 
} 
else if (result == SetImageFeedResult.ChangeDisabled) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: call succeeded but group policy has the lock screen image slide show turned off."; 
} 
else // (result == SetImageFeedResult.UserCanceled) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: the specified URL was not set as the default."; 
}
```

result is always equal SetImageFeedResult.Success

Comment: Have you tried running that method without it using the lockscreen, see what it returns might be worth a try see if there's an exception that's returned, might be a permission set needs to be changed for Windows 10 but Windows 8 apps should work as-is

Comment: Has anyone figured this out for Windows 10?... I have been trying to get the sample w/ different RSS feeds to work for weeks now. I tried before RTM and then immediately after.. and now (a few weeks later) I still can't get the LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync to work with any RSS feed. I do, however, now get the prompt asking if I will allow the app to set my lockscreen (which I wasn't getting before RTM).

Comment: I have the same problem, but I haven't tested this in RTM version. In Windows 10 this doesn't work and I don't know why?

Comment: This API is still completely broken and unavailable on Phone (unable to set single image as lockscreen and also unable to set an RSS feed). Tablet/PC is also unable to set to an RSS feed, but setting a single image as lockscreen is inconsistently working on different devices.

Comment: Does anybody know, why Microsoft has closed that API?

Answer (score 0):

For your question, it seems that this method is working with windows 8.1 only

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.requestsetimagefeedasync?view=winrt-19041):
`LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync(Uri)`
Registers an RSS image feed to be used as a lock screen slideshow. **(Windows 8.1 only)**